# Issue with styles in HTMLbody in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, format

I have an issue with setup email body using VBA. I need to customized e mail body with deferent font sizes and colors. therefore i have used .HTMLBody function.
Once, i have executed the code it works fine but didn't give any format in the outlook display.
If anyone can help regarding this issue it really appreciate.

VBA CODE:

```
 .HTMLBody = "Hi <strong>All</strong>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Your task has already overdue! Please focus your kind attention here." & "<br>" & _
                "<br>" & _
                "<strong>" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "Task &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" & "</span>" & "</strong>:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "testing task testing task" & "</span> " & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "<strong>" & "Decision" & "</strong>" & "</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "Test action test action" & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "<strong>Due Date&nbsp;" & "</strong>" & "</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "21/1/2021" & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 12px;" & ">" & "This is system generated email from Measure and Monitoring team." & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 12px;" & ">" & "If you already completed or any convenience regarding this e mail please reply here." & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 10px;" & ">" & "Generated Date : 1/1/2021" & "</span>" & _
                "<br>"
```

[image]

Comment: *i have executed the code it works fine but didn't give any format in the outlook display*
What does that mean? The text is formatted with bold so it obviously works

Comment: Hi. No i need to add colors to that words. I have wrote the HTML code using  "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);"  but its not give a defined color. I am wondering why is that

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have half of it wrong. If it doesn't work then have a look of how VBA will format it. One error: **<span style=color: rgb(41, 105, 176);>**
No quotation marks after **style=**

Test it out yourself:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim HTMLBody As String

HTMLBody = "Hi <strong>All</strong>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Your task has already overdue! Please focus your kind attention here." & "<br>" & _
                "<br>" & _
                "<strong>" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "Task &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" & "</span>" & "</strong>:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "testing task testing task" & "</span> " & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "<strong>" & "Decision" & "</strong>" & "</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "Test action test action" & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "color: rgb(41, 105, 176);" & ">" & "<strong>Due Date&nbsp;" & "</strong>" & "</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:" & "<span style=" & "color: rgb(184, 49, 47);" & ">" & "21/1/2021" & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 12px;" & ">" & "This is system generated email from Measure and Monitoring team." & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 12px;" & ">" & "If you already completed or any convenience regarding this e mail please reply here." & "</span>" & "<br>" & _
                "<span style=" & "font-size: 10px;" & ">" & "Generated Date : 1/1/2021" & "</span>" & _
                "<br>" & vbCrLf
Debug.Print HTMLBody

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, If i removed the quotation marks after style= , it gave me an error and code didn't works.

Comment: Could you please tell us what error you've got then?

Comment: Error mean if i remove the quotation marks, & write the code as follows,  "<strong>" & "<span style= color: rgb(41, 105, 176);>" & it didn't give any color. It only bold the text. same as results i showed in figure.

Comment: You cannot remove the quotation marks, that not valid CSS. Please tell us what error you get with the quotation marks in place.